# Summation of an expression $\sum_{h=0}^{\ln n}\frac{h}{2^h}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can be we get the closed form for this expression?

> $$
> \sum_{h=0}^{\ln n}\frac{h}{2^h}
> $$

Comment: Which expression?

Comment: where can we find that expression?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful finite evaluation:
$$
1+r+r^2+...+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ and multiplying by $r$ you get
$$
\sum_{h=0}^Nhr^h=r+2r^2+3r^3+...+Nr^N=r\frac{1-r^{N+1}}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{(N+1)r^{N+1}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1, \tag2
$$ then if you put $r:=\dfrac12$, $N=\lfloor \log n\rfloor $, you obtain an answer to your question.

Comment: Those formulas hold for any $r\neq1$... Cheers!

Comment: @barto You are right! Thus for $|r|<1$, which is enough here :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $f(x)$ be the geometric progression

$$f(x)=\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor \log(n)\rfloor}x^h \tag 1$$

and note that

$$xf'(x)=\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}h x^h$$

Then, let $x=1/2$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark